# How can I center text relative to a single letter of another text?

Tags: html, css

I have two letters. One is "M" at a very large font. Another is a single-digit number. I want the number to overlap the text and be centered with the M, and for them to stay aligned at the same relative scale at any font size, as if they were one character. I also don't want the number to take up any space in the following line of text. The M should be able to stay inline as well, without causing a line break. Is this possible?

I've been trying to use negative margins scaled by em units, but the two letters still fall out of alignment.

```html
<span style="font-size:200%;"><!-- arbitrary font size for testing to make sure it scales --><span style="margin-right:-1ch;"><span style="font-size:500%; -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; user-select: none;">M</span><span style="top:-1px; left:-2em; position:relative; color:blue; display:inline-block;">1</span>
</span></span>test text to make sure the 1 doesn't take up space
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Blair! If you can, create a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) or JSbin example, so that the community can see and understand your question further. I've done this for you here and that you can edit and share as needed: https://jsfiddle.net/9r5ct8zg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I made for you. You can check it's working since I used percentages and `em` values which both depend on the size of the M-letter. You can play with it and decrease the font-size of `.big-letter` span and it will all be aligned in any size. Instead of using two spans (two other tags) to form one element, we usually use `::before` and `::after` selectors.

If you want to preserve the opportunity to modify the value of that number inside that letter, I would recommend using the following structure:

```js
let test = document.getElementById('test');
let fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(test, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');

let increment = document.getElementById('increment');
increment.addEventListener('click', () => {
 fontSize = (parseFloat(fontSize) + 4) + 'px';
 test.style.fontSize = fontSize;
});

let decrement = document.getElementById('decrement');
decrement.addEventListener('click', () => {
 fontSize = (parseFloat(fontSize) - 4) + 'px';
 test.style.fontSize = fontSize;
});
```

```css
#test {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.big-letter {
  font-size: 200%;
  margin-right: -0.2em;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
}

.big-letter span {
  content: '1';
  font-size: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 11%;
  left: 40%;
  color: blue;
}

#increment {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 65px;
}

#decrement {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 155px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <span class="big-letter">
    M
  </span>
  <span class="big-letter">
    M
    <span>
      2
    </span>
  </span>
  test text to make sure the 1 doesn't take up space
  <button id="increment">
    increment
  </button>
  <button id="decrement">
    decrement
  </button>
</div>
```

I hope that helped you.

P.S. I updated the snippet that you could see it changing.

Comment: That helps a great deal, thank you! But let's say I want to edit the number within the html as well. How could I best do that?

Comment: So you want to have different numbers 'attached' to different letters?

Comment: Correct! Being able to edit the number is more important to me than editing the letter, but ideally I would like both, as long as the surrounding text acts as if it's only the big letter.

Comment: I updated my reply and now you can edit both number and letter using HTML and edit position using CSS. Remember, use only `em` and `%` to edit it since that's how you keep proportions between things. If you like my answer and think it answers your question, feel free to vote for it and accept as the answer :) Also, let me know if you have any other questions.